# php Sum specific value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I have array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [impr] => 800000
            [clicks] => 500
            [ctr] => 0.000625
            [cvr] => 0.04
            [cpc] => 0.14024
            [cpm] => 0.08765
            [cpa] => 3.51
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [impr] => 889000
            [clicks] => 600
            [ctr] => 0.000625
            [cvr] => 0.08
            [cpc] => 0.34024
            [cpm] => 0.08765
            [cpa] => 4.41
        )

)
```

I want to sum that array and get result like this

```
Array
(
   [impr] => 1689000
   [clicks] => 1100
   [ctr] => 0.0025
   [cvr] => 0.12
   [cpc] => 0.96096
   [cpm] => 0.1753
   [cpa] => 7.92
)
```

I trying to using

> array_sum()

with looping my array to that array_sum, but I getting error like this

array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

And even try looping with foreach and using += for sum the value, but the result is not I want

the result is 800000889000

Can anyone suggest me the better code for getting my result like I want

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an array that will contain the sums:

```
$sumArray = array(
    "impr" => 0,
    "clicks" => 0,
    "ctr" => 0,
    "cvr" => 0,
    "cpc" => 0,
    "cpm" => 0,
    "cpa" => 0,
);
```

Then do the calculating:

```
foreach ($oldArray as $row)
{
    foreach ($rows as $key => $value)
    {
        $sumArray[$key] += $value;
    }
}
```

Then to view your results, just do:

```
print_r($sumArray);
```

**NOTE:** I am assuming that the keys that you have in your original array don't have the brackets around them, however if the actual key strings do have the brackets, then use the following code for creating $sumArray:

```
$sumArray = array(
    "[impr]" => 0,
    "[clicks]" => 0,
    "[ctr]" => 0,
    "[cvr]" => 0,
    "[cpc]" => 0,
    "[cpm]" => 0,
    "[cpa]" => 0,
);
```

Comment: how if I want to make array like this
`[1689000, 1100, 0.00125, 0.12, 0.48048, 0.1753, 7.92]` ?

Comment: You could create another foreach loop after my previous code like so: `$otherAnswer = array(); foreach ($sumArray as $value){$otherAnswer[] = $value;}` What that will do is create another array called `$otherAnswer` which doesn't contain the `$key` values (impr, clicks, etc...)

Comment: @ArieSastra no problem :)